# Prove that if $\{1,a\}\trianglelefteq G$ then $a$ is in the center of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. Show, for $a\in G$, that if the subset $\lbrace 
1,a \rbrace$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then $a$ is in the center of $G$. Prove that $N:=\lbrace 1,x^5 \rbrace$ is a normal subgroup of $D_{10}$.

How do I show the first claim that if the subset $\lbrace 1,a \rbrace$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then $a$ is in the center of $G$? I'm not entirely sure how to incorporate that. Here is my proof so far:

*Proof.* Let $a\in G$ and suppose $H\trianglelefteq G$. Trivially, the identity 1 belongs to the center. Hence, $x^5$ commutes with every element of $G$. Moreover, $gx^5g^{-1}=gg^{-1}x^5=x^5$. Thus, we have that $x^5$ is in the center of $D_{10}$.

Answer (score 4):

If $N \lhd G$ then for every element $x$ in $N$ and every element $g \in G$ it holds that $gxg^{-1} \in N$. Hence, take $a \in N$. Either $gag^{-1} = 1$ or $gag^{-1} = a$. The first one is not possible, since $gag^{-1} = 1$ implies $a = g^{-1}1g = 1$, while $a \neq 1$. So $gag^{-1}=a$, and hence $ga = ag$ for all $g \in G$.

Answer (score 1):

It must be $Ng = gN, \forall g \in G$, where $N:=\{1,a\}$. Now, $Ng=\{g,ag\}$ and $gN=\{g,ga\}$, so $Ng=gN, \forall g \in G \color{red}{\Rightarrow} ag=ga, \forall g \in G \Rightarrow a \in Z(G)$. Note the implication in red holds because $a \ne 1$ by hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Use the normality condition: $gHg^{-1}=H,\,\forall g$.